# Querying two tables with an union

Tags: mysql, datatable

I have a very simple mysql query, I want to fetch some 'data' from two tables table1 and table2 as soon as this 'data' is in one row containing a precise 'id', so I ran a prepared request :

```
'select data from (
    select data from table1 union select data from table2) 
 where id = :id'
```

But it doesn't seem to work (btw, I tried simply `'select data from table1, table2 where id = :id '`)
but it didn't work. Someone could help, I don't know where I am missing something ?

Comment: that's not valid sql ... unless 'data' is a column name

Comment: I grabbed it from a tutorial, why is it not? (sorry I am not familiar yet to sql)

Comment: start here:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select * from table1  where id = :id
 union all
 select * from table2  where id = :id
```

Answer (score 1):

Unions are complex and unwarranted in MySQL, I would rather rely on JOIN to execute my statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a join. There are multiple types of joins, where the most common are `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.

`LEFT JOIN` returns the rows, even if the matched data does not exists, and return null for the joined data.

`INNER JOIN` requires the matched data to exists and doesn't return anything if the matched data doesn't exist.

Example using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
   table1.*,
   table2.*
FROM
   table1
   INNER JOIN table2 ON ( table1.id = table2.id )
WHERE
   id = :id
```

Comment: No I need an union, because I want to select the same 'data' appearing from table1 and table2

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use union, if what you want to do is get the data from table1 and table2, where the ID in table2 is 1, and the ID in table1 is 1, you can use the JOIN. Nothing in the sql you posted, requires you to use a UNION.

Comment: Sure I didn't really understand the IINER JOIN process, will it return

Comment: If you use `INNER JOIN table2 ON ( table1.id = table2.id )`, and id = 1, table2.id[1] must exist, or it will return 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Select table1.data, table2.data from table1 where table1.id = table2.id

Comment: No I need to fetch the same 'data' appearing both in table1 and table2

Comment: Sure I didn't understand the INNER JOIN process, what will it return for each row in that case, I'll have a row with two copies of 'data' for each occurrence of id ?